# "SelectedItem" Combobox property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, selecteditem

I'm working on an app and I encounter a problem.
I have the following Combobox (.xaml)

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding IngredientListeSource}"                              
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedIngredient}"
          IsEditable="True" IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
               <TextBlock Text=" ("/>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding IDmesure}"/>
               <TextBlock Text=")"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

The "IngredientListeSource" is an ObservableCollection of "Ingredient" (ObservableCollection) that I fill with the following code in my ViewModel

```
private List<Ingredient> getIngredientListeSource()
    {
        List<Ingredient> itemListe = new List<Ingredient>();

        foreach (var item in IngredientProvider.selectAll())
        {
            itemListe.Add(new Ingredient 
            {
                Name = item.Name,
                IDmesure = item.IDmesure,
            });
        }

        return itemListe;
    }
```

The ComboBox's list is an object (Ingredient) list and not a string list. That's why, when I select an object, the "[SelectedItem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0cnH.png)" property doesn't display the string selected.

I looked for on google, I read that it (maybe) need to use an overriding of ToString() property, but I don't understand how to do that.

Could you help me to find the best way to fix my issue ?

PS : If necessary, the "IngredientProvider" class

```
public static List<Ingredient> selectAll()
    {
        List<Ingredient> list = new List<Ingredient>();
        DBUtils dBUtils = new DBUtils();
        MySqlConnection connection = dBUtils.initialize();
        bool stateConnection = dBUtils.openConnection(connection);

        string query = "SELECT ingredient.Name AS NameIngredient, mesure.Name AS NameMesure FROM ingredient " +
                "INNER JOIN mesure ON ingredient.IDmesure = mesure.IDmesure";

        //Open connection
        if (stateConnection == true)
        {
            //Create Command
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

            //Create a data reader and Execute the command
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                list.Add(new Ingredient
                {
                    Name = dataReader["NameIngredient"].ToString(),
                    IDmesure = dataReader["NameMesure"].ToString(),
                });
            }
        }
        dBUtils.closeConnection(connection);
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if that is what you are asking for, but if you want to select an Ingredient item by its Name property, set `SelectedValuePath="Name"` and bind `SelectedValue` instead if `SelectedItem`.

Comment: You probably just want to remove `IsEditable="True"`.

Comment: Ok, I understand. IsEditable=true is a property to modify the list. Right ? :)
I used this property to help the user to find his choice. So, I think I need to study the `TextSearch.TextPath` property

Comment: The property `IsEditable` in the .xaml file allow to get or set from a text box of the ComboBox. But in my case I can't use this function because of the structure of my list of object.
The matrix displayed at the bottom in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.combobox.iseditable?view=netcore-3.1) should explain the behavior of `IsEditable` and `IsReadOnly` properties.